# How do I get a square to follow the mouse coordinates on a mouse click?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drag-and-drop, event-handling, dom-events

I am having trouble trying to get a canvas based square to follow the mouse. Here is the method I am trying to use:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
     document.getElementById('debug3').innerHTML = 'works';//Just debug stuff.

     for (i=0;i>10;i++) { //to loop through squares.
        document.getElementById('debug5').innerHTML = 'works';
        if (mouseX >= square[i].x - 20 && mouseX <= square[i].x + 40 && mouseY >= square[i].y - 20 && mouseY <= square[i].y + 40) {//To see if mouse coordinates equal square ones.
            square[i].x = mouseX;//Just defining that mouse coordinates equal square ones.
            square[i].y = mouseY;
            document.getElementById('debug6').innerHTML = 'works';
        }
    }
}, true);
```

I have ten squares I want to choose from, so I put they're coordinates in a array. The `-20` and `+40` are so I can have a imaginary square that signifies the range which the click is accepted (It is very hard to click on one pixel). These squares are supposed to be animated, so I have a range twice their area (the squares have an area of 400 pixels). The for loop is to loop through the possible squares the user choose. After that, it's pretty obvious.

My problem is that that doesn't happen. I stopped animating the squares to make them easier to click for me, but the code just isn't working. According to my debug statements, when I press, the event listener works. That's the first debug statement. The thing is that the for loop never gets triggered and my second debug statement never works. Therefore, nor does my third (you might see them labelled 3, 5, and 6: the first two are my mouse coordinates and the fourth is the mouse up event, which has the same problem).

EDIT: Here is the code that defines mouseX and mouseY.

```
function initCanvas() {
        context.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(event) {
                var mouseX = Math.floor(event.clientX);
                var mouseY = Math.floor(event.clientY);

                document.getElementById('debug1').innerHTML = mouseX;
                document.getElementById('debug2').innerHTML = mouseY;//test debug stuff
        });
 }
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
        initCanvas();
});
```

I've tested this. It works. It is not the problem.

Comment: PS: if you need the entire program, let me know.

Comment: mouseX and mouseY are not defined within the code you show.

Comment: mouseX and mouseY are defined. This is not my whole program (hence my previous comment).

Comment: Please answer. Been waiting here forever...    Thanks to those that do and to the ONE COMMENT I got on the question

Comment: You did not answer my comment (maybe unclear : 'are mouseX/mouseY  defined, and how are they computed ?' would have been a better comment) If you want to dramatically increase the chances of answer, provide a jsbin/jsfiddle/codepen/... worth a thousand words :-)

Comment: I don't know how to use any of those very well (codepen, jsfiddle, etc), and I personally dislike them. Not to be mean, but if you want/need more of my code, I am happy to post it on the post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't bang your head on a wal : you wrote : for (i=0;i **** >*****10 ; i++)

Comment: Maybe you need to declare mouseX and mouseY as global variable? By declaring them in the same hierarchy as your functions?

Comment: Yea! Now for loop works! But, in the for loop, it is not reading the if statement (i fixed the scope problem by declaring the variable at the beginning).